# Problem in switching views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application there are 2 views (switching on button pressed), one is to display a web link and another one is to display some text. In 1st view I have taken a UIWebView and showing a web link in it. In 2nd view I have taken UITextView n displaying some text. 
Now, as I switching these view by button pressed sometimes web view shows text view and sometime textview and same thing is happening with textview, mean randomly these views show any view either web or text.
Both views are totally different to each other.

Here is the code:

**web.h**

```
@interface web : UIViewController {
    NSInteger bTag;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webShow;
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger bTag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webShow;
-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id) sender;
@end
```

**web.m**

```
#import "help.h"
#import "web.h"


@implementation web

@synthesize bTag;
@synthesize webShow;

-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    self.bTag=[sender tag];

    switch (self.bTag)
    {

        case 1:
        {
            help *hv=[[help alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            hv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            [self presentModalViewController:hv animated:YES];  
            [hv release];
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            web *wv=[[web alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            wv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            [self presentModalViewController:wv animated:YES];  
            [wv release];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.unicurd.com.sg/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webShow loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [webShow release];
}
@end
```

**help.h**

```
@interface help : UIViewController {


    NSInteger bTag;
    }

@property(nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger bTag;


-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id) sender;

@end
```

**help.m**

```
#import "help.h"
#import "web.h"


@implementation help

@synthesize bTag;

-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    self.bTag=[sender tag];

    switch (self.bTag)
    {

        case 1:
        {
            help *hv=[[help alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            hv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            [self presentModalViewController:hv animated:YES];  
            [hv release];
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            web *wv=[[web alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            wv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            [self presentModalViewController:wv animated:YES];  
            [wv release];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

I am displaying text in help.xib by taking UITextView.

Comment: i think what you want is a UITabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code as reference

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(id) sender
{
     if(SwitchToLinkView)
     {
         [myTextView removeFromSuperview];
         [self.view addSubview:myWebLinkView];
     }
     else 
     {
         [myWebLinkView removeFromSuperview];
         [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[dismissModalViewControllerAnimated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Comment: I can't use this because I have many(5) views so in switch case there are 5 cases so that I can switch from any view to any view. And through dismissModalViewControllerAnimated we can switch to just previous view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the view randomly , as i couldn't understand the logic inside the your ibaction.